# Open app without triggering SiriKit automation

Tags: swift, xcode, sirikit, ios17, appintents

I am currently trying to create a "blocker" app that blocks a certain app if a condition is not fulfilled. There are other apps like this out on the App Store and one of them is one sec. Their app works such as you set an automation in shortcuts that opens the one sec app whenever another app (let's say instagram) opens. Then in the one sec app the user makes the choice of whether or not they want to continue to the app. If the choice is to continue instagram opens again.

Here is a video of how it works (they don't show the navigation back to instagram though) https://one-sec.app/assets/videos/one%20sec%20website%20animation-1.mov

I have tried to do this using UIApplication.shared.open but this results in an infinite loop. Any idea on how they might av accomplished this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You probably need to have some logic in your shortcut to decide not to open your app if the user has just chosen to actually launch Instagram.